# MSSQLScript not executing from one server against another server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Friends,

Problem:
I've written following queries in a script intending to ALTER and UPDATE the Table1's data at ONCE. Now the Table1 is in Skyline_Data on the server *SQLServer2*. I wanted to execute the script below from Another Server, say *SQLServer1*. Even if we change the order of the statements, it obviously is impossible to execute the script by sitting on SQLServer1.
But My main script has to be run in SQLServer1 and the script below is just a part of that Main.

Question: 
Is there any other alternative so that I can run the script from one server i.e SQLServer1 against another i.e SQLServer2??

Please do kindly answer to this ASAP!

```
 alter TABLE  SQLServer2.Skyline_data.dbo.Table1 add ToConvert Bit
 default(1) Not null

 alter TABLE  SQLServer2.Skyline_data.dbo.Table1 add  fname VARCHAR(255),
 mname VARCHAR(255), lname VARCHAR(255)

 update  SQLServer2.Skyline_data.dbo.Table1 set ToConvert = 1 where
 Name Is null

 update a set a.fname =     LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.udf_SplitText(Name,' ', 1))),
    a.lname = 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.udf_SplitText(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.udf_SplitText(Name, '
 ', 2))), ' ', 1)))     FROM SQLServer2.Skyline_data.dbo.Table1 a
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

YOu should be able to run it on another server assuming that the databases are the same.

```
alter TABLE  SQLServer2.Skyline_data.dbo.Table1 add ToConvert Bit default(1) Not null

alter TABLE  SQLServer2.Skyline_data.dbo.Table1 add  fname VARCHAR(255),
                                   mname VARCHAR(255), lname VARCHAR(255)

update  SQLServer2.Skyline_data.dbo.Table1 set ToConvert = 1 where Name Is null

update a set a.fname = LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.udf_SplitText(Name,' ', 1))),
a.lname =  LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.udf_SplitText(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.udf_SplitText(Name, '
', 2))), ' ', 1)))     
FROM SQLServer2.Skyline_data.dbo.Table1 a
```

My only question is that you have gosql02 some places and SQLServer2 in other places.  Make sure that the server to table plath is corect SQLServer2.Skyline_data.dbo.Table1